# Function once that accepts a callback as input and returns a function.

Tags: javascript, closures

Write a function once that accepts a callback as input and returns a function. When the returned function is called the first time, it should call the callback and return that output. If it is called any additional times, instead of calling the callback again it will simply return the output value from the first time it was called.

Help!I got an error like Syntax-error Illegal return statement I got stuck at writing closure for this challenge above and here it is my code:

```js
function once(func) {
  var called = 0,result;
 function inner(num){
    if(!result && called <2){
      called++;
      result = func(num);
      return result;
    }else{
      return result;
    }
    }
    
  }
  return inner;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare called variable outside of the function

```js
var called = 0;
function once(func) {
  var result;
 function inner(num){
    if(!result && called <2){
      called++;
      result = func(num);
      return result;
    }else{
      return result;
    }
    }

  return inner;
}
```

Comment: When running this snippet it is still firing the error `"Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal return statement"`...

Comment: @AlexanderNied give extra `}` for that gives an error. I have fixed the error. please check.

Comment: Yep, that resolved it.

Comment: Thanks man. I just misread my code and there is an extra bracket made my code error guys.Thanks.

Comment: @MinThihaMaung Can you please mark this answer correct if answered is useful

Answer (score 0):

> I got an error like Syntax-error Illegal return statement

```
  } //<--- extra/un-wanted
  return inner;
}
```

Try this:

```js
var add = (function(cb) {
  var done = false;
  var data = 0;
  return function(num) {
    if (!done) {
      done = true;
      data = (num + 1);
    }
    cb(data);
  };
});

var bar = function(res) {
  console.log('bar, res = ', res);
};

var foo = add(bar);

foo(2);
foo(1);
```

Comment: Thanks man. I just misread my code and there is an extra bracket made my code error guys.Thanks